# Is Comcast TV API open to public?

Tags: television

I am thinking the build my own home system that can do basic tuning channels or view lineup for my Comcast cable TV, like xfinity TV App does.

I am wondering if someone know Comcast open their API? or is there a way that can do it?

Thanks

Lewis

Comment: Did you try asking them first or did you come straight here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you'll have to program against a 3rd party system that uses a CableCard.

To my knowledge the only way you can do something like this is to write a plug-in for [Media Center on Windows with a CableCARD](http://hd.engadget.com/2009/05/12/how-to-install-a-cablecard-tuner-in-your-diy-media-center/).  Take a look at the [Windows Media Center SDK Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms816327.aspx) and see if it has the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, everything I've seen suggests that it's a private API. Which makes sense, they probably want you to have to use their services instead of creating your own.